# Will powering a device with a source that can provide more current than the device needs damage the device?

Tags: voltage, batteries, current, lead-acid, ampere-hour

I am trying to build a power supply for my LCD monitor.

It consumes 19.5V and 1.7 amperes.

I am using a 12 volt 16 ampere lead acid battery. I have used a step up boost converter to increase the voltage to 19.5V, but I am not able to decrease the current. It is still 16 amperes only.

If I use this power supply with 19.5 volt and 16 amperes, will it damage my LCD monitor?

Comment: Don't worry, law of conservation of energy has decreased your amp rating from 16 when you stepped up the voltage. Besides your lcd monitor will consume only the current it needs.

Comment: `It consumes 19.5V and 1.7 amperes.` ... that is somewhat incorrect ... this is more accurate ... `It requires 19.5 V and can draw up to 1.7 A`

Comment: think about this: the power supply that you are replacing is probably able to source 1.7 A ... the monitor probably draws only a few mA in standby mode ... why does the monitor not burn up when in standby mode?

Answer (score 0):

Golden rule:

```
Voltage is pushed, current is pulled
```

That's a poetic though slightly imprecise way of stating that the load (the monitor) sets the current, not the source (the battery). At a given voltage, the load decides how much current it wants, and that is all that it takes.

The fact that the source *could* provide more current to *some other* load that wants more current, has no effect on *this* particular load. Therefore, no, the monitor will not be damaged.

Comment: "That's the truth." says ELI the ICE man.